# Bundle the js files based on requirejs structure

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

We have `requirejs`.

I have mentioned the paths and the shim in requirejs.

Here, when I load the controller in angularjs router, the files are loading separately.

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    baseUrl: 'Folder',
    waitSeconds: 200,
    paths: {
        // Jquery
        'Angular': 'Angular path',
        'FileA': 'FileA',
        'FileB': 'FileB',

  },
 shim: {
'FileB'{
    Deps:'FileA'
},
'FileA'{
    Deps:'Angular'
},
}
```

When I require FileB, it will automatically retrieve fileA and angular file.

But in this case, I am requesting three http request for the three files.

**Is there any solution that, based on requirejs structure bundling the files?**
So that when I request the file, I will get the single file instead of multiple files

Answer (score -1):

If there is any dependency between the files that you are trying to bundle then bundling them in separate files doesn't make any sense.

However if you are sure that dependencies would not be any problem you can use `bundle` a new feature from `requirejs`:

```
requirejs.config({
  bundles: {
    'shared': ['angular'],
    'fileA': ['fileA'],
    'fileB': ['fileB'],
    // etc...
  }
});
```

Also you can add your template to the bundle which is awesome. More info [here](http://webroo.org/articles/2014-03-30/using-the-new-require-js-bundles-feature/).